# O que é necessário para conectar a um banco SQLSERVER externo à minha aplicação?

Tags: php, sql-server

Tenho uma hospedagem na qual eu preciso conectar a um banco *SQLServer* externo num sistema php que estou criando. Insiro todos os dados corretamente mas sempre dá erro de conexão mostrando a mensagem:

> `mssql_connect()`: *Unable to connect to server:xxxxxxxxx*

Será que existe algum tipo de incompatibilidade na minha hospedagem para conexões com o banco da Microsoft? É necessário algo a mais, um plugin ou algo do tipo? No MySQL ele conecta normalmente.

Comment: O servidor é local? ou em nuvem? se local, o servidor, esta instalado na sua maquina? ou em algum servidor dentro da rede LAN? se estiver na sua maquina, esta usando a instancia certa? exemplo: 172.16.0.13\SQLEXPRESS? se for em LAN ja verificou se o SQL está habilitado para trabalhar em rede? se for em nuvem, geralmente temos que liberar o nosso IP  para fazer a conexão.

Comment: Olá Thomas. Não está na minha máquina. O sistema está em um servidor nosso e o banco está num servidor do cliente. Ainda não verifiquei se o IP está liberado, farei isso agora. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Matheus, verifique o redirecionamento de portas, no seu cliente, verifique as regras de firewall, liberando a por TCP 1433 (Porta Default do SQL)

Comment: Antes de tentar conectar com o seu código, tente usar o SQL Server Management Studio. Se ele não conseguir, você pode não estar usando os parâmetros corretos ou a conexão com o banco pode não estar aberta.

Comment: Como esta sua string de conexão?

Comment: Marconcílio, o erro aparece logo no início do script.

$host = 'http://www.endereco.ddns.net';
$user = 'user';
$pass= 'password';
mssql_connect($host, $user, $pass);